# Clearing a table before insertion

Tags: sql-server, database, linq

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a script file, like this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ON
.....
Many insert statements
.....
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Cars] OFF
```

Question is if I can add something before this so that the table is cleared and updated with the new insertions?

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename>`? This deletes _all_ records from the table.

Comment: Wow easy and fast, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ON
.....
Many insert statements
.....
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Cars] OFF
```

This removes **all** records from the table faster and using fewer system resources then `DELETE`.

Comment: And can't be done inside a transaction *(which may or may not matter to the OP)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars]
```

That will delete all records in the specified table.

Note that `TRUNCATE TABLE` will reset the counter on `IDENTITY` columns to the initial value in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  If you don't want to do that, you can use:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Cars]
```

Comment: And can't be done inside a transaction *(which may or may not matter to the OP)*

Comment: @MatBailie [That's actually not correct](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/04/sql-server-rollback-truncate-command-in-transaction/).  It's not logged as a record removal; it's logged as a page deallocation.  However, it *is* logged because you can roll it back.